# Post Request Payload to SOAP Webservice using Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

Using request payload, web service, operation names, soap action and all the required details, I need to invoke a soap web service. This has to be done without generating the proxy and any other classes.

I get the request payload as a String, corresponding webservice and operation details to my program and I need to directly post the payload to the webservice by attaching the required webservice policy.

Please suggest the way to achieve it. Kindly let me know if it is not clear

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use a proxy, such as this is a homework assignment?  Could you post your WSDL file?

Comment: Why you want to send as XML and not call service with required payload as web service expects. This is a bad approach and will lead to lot of issues later.

Comment: Actually we are planning to implement it as a re usable  one so that in the future if any soap webservice details are passed to this program, it should be able to invoke that particular webservice without any code changes.

Comment: Sheetal - sorry to mention as an xml but the request payload as like a soap webservice expects but should happen dynamically.

Comment: Hey. Got your point. But it seems a bad integration approach. Wrong granularity, etc..

Comment: Is there any way to implement it?